# Grid loadMask malfunction.Set loadMask target config

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5, loadmask

The grid loadMask has some problems.

`LoadMask:true` does not work.

If I choose to do as follows:

```
viewConfig: {
  loadMask: {msg: 'Loading records ...'}
}
```

It works but the mask only covers the grid body, excluding toolbares.

I tried `maskElement: 'el'` but did not work.

I do not intend to use setLoading ().

One solution might be target to my grid:

```
viewConfig: {
     loadMask: {msg: 'Loading records ...', target: this} 
 }
```

But `target: this` does not work.

Any idea how to get and set grid reference in the config target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to override the createMask function of AbstractView.

```
Ext.define('Test',{
    override:'Ext.view.AbstractView',
    privates:{
        createMask:function(mask) {
            if(this.ownerCt) {
                if(!Ext.isObject(mask)) mask = {target:this.ownerCt};
                else if(!mask.target) mask.target = this.ownerCt;
            }
            this.callParent(arguments);
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/15b9)

Comment: Okay, seems not all views have an ownerCt. Updated the code to respect that.